# Can anyone help me with installing eclipse bugzilla plugin?

Tags: eclipse, bugzilla

can anyone help me with installing eclipse bugzilla plugin? Where can I find tutorial on how to install it?

[EDIT] I got it http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/e3.4/ or you can use pulse explorer to find the plugin for you

Comment: So you don't need to install Bugzilla? Question title is misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this on the website were your downloaded the plugin.

[EDIT] If you use the built-in "Install new software", you can get help menu under "Help Contents". Look for "Mylyn" because the Bugzilla integration is part of the Mylyn plugin.

Mylyn web site: http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn

You can find a tutorial here: http://www.tasktop.com/mylyn/

Comment: I could help you if you would provide me with information but you forgot it ... :) "eclipse bugzilla plugin" isn't really saying much. Are you talking about the Mylyn plugin?

Comment: I found the answer but because I forgot to tick I ll accept your answer